# Ws-Security 1.1 Header Security not understood

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to write a client to call a web service that uses WS-Security 1.1
. They provided a WSDL and I generated the code through Visual Studio.

**(UPDATE)** Here is the binding

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IConnectService">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Here is my request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
     ...
        <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="7c10648f-984d-4920-849e-b0afb586f871">
                <u:Created>2016-08-24T13:08:06.118Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2016-08-24T14:08:06.118Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:UsernameToken>
                <o:Username>actualUsername</o:Username>
                <o:Password>realPassword</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Through Fiddler, I can see that the data I want is getting returned.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2014-05-02T14:02:46.988Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2014-05-02T14:07:46.988Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    ....
    The data I really want
```

However, in Visual Studio I get this error:

> The header 'Security' from the namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding.

How do I correct this error? Given that I see the data coming back, it seems like a configuration problem.

Comment: What does your client binding look like? Are you using basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding?

Comment: I'm using basicHttpBinding. I just added the details to the question.

Comment: I have same problem with same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found solutions, but I had to modified.

```
public class CustomCredentials : ClientCredentials
{
    public CustomCredentials()
    { }

    protected CustomCredentials(CustomCredentials cc)
        : base(cc)
    { }

    public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenManager CreateSecurityTokenManager()
    {
        return new CustomSecurityTokenManager(this);
    }

    protected override ClientCredentials CloneCore()
    {
        return new CustomCredentials(this);
    }
}
public class CustomSecurityTokenManager : ClientCredentialsSecurityTokenManager
{
    public CustomSecurityTokenManager(CustomCredentials cred)
        : base(cred)
    { }

    public override System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenSerializer CreateSecurityTokenSerializer(System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenVersion version)
    {
        return new CustomTokenSerializer(System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityVersion.WSSecurity11);
    }
}
public class CustomTokenSerializer : WSSecurityTokenSerializer
{
    public CustomTokenSerializer(SecurityVersion sv)
        : base(sv)
    { }

    protected override void WriteTokenCore(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token)
    {
        UserNameSecurityToken userToken = token as UserNameSecurityToken;

        string tokennamespace = "o";

        DateTime created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string createdStr = created.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");

        Random r = new Random();
        var nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GetSHA1String(created + r.Next().ToString())));


       // string password = GetSHA1String(nonce + createdStr + userToken.Password);

        writer.WriteRaw(string.Format(
        "<{0}:UsernameToken u:Id=\"" + "UsernameToken-ABCD" +
        "\" xmlns:u=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\">" +
        "<{0}:Username>" + userToken.UserName + "</{0}:Username>" +
        "<{0}:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText\">" +
        userToken.Password + "</{0}:Password>" +
        "<{0}:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\">" +
        nonce + "</{0}:Nonce>" +
        "<u:Created>" + createdStr + "</u:Created></{0}:UsernameToken>", tokennamespace));
    }

    protected string GetSHA1String(string phrase)
    {
        UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1Hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] hashedDataBytes = sha1Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(phrase));
        return ByteArrayToString(hashedDataBytes);
    }

    protected String ByteArrayToString(byte[] inputArray)
    {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
        {
            output.Append(inputArray[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return output.ToString();
    }

}
 public static YOURContractClient CreateRealTimeOnlineProxy(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();

        var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
        security.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
        security.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
        security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10;

        var encoding = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;

        var transport = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
        transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000; // 20 megs

        binding.Elements.Add(security);
        binding.Elements.Add(encoding);
        binding.Elements.Add(transport);

        YOURContractClient client = new YOURContractClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(url));
        client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Remove<System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials>();
        client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new CustomCredentials());

        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;

        return client;
    }
```

Use it:

```
 var cl = CreateRealTimeOnlineProxy(URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have customBinding, your config have to be:

```
  <customBinding>
            <binding name="ImportsTaxPaySoap12Binding">
            <security includeTimestamp="true" 
                      authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" 
                      defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256" 
                      requireDerivedKeys="true"
                      messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecu
                      reConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11
                      BasicSecurityProfile10">
            </security>
            <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12"></textMessageEncoding>
            <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" />
            </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer for .NET version 6+. Currently `SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement()` is not supported and there is no proper documentation that describes how to make an Issued Token Authentication. So my solution involves injecting the necessary security header via a `ClientMessageInspector` implementation, this way you can successfully make requests to the endpoint but the sad part is even if the response is successful your WCF client will throw the above error. To get around that error I have implemented `AfterReceiveReply` method to remove the security header from the message like the below :

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
        var r = reply.Headers.FindHeader("Security",
            "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
        reply.Headers.RemoveAt(r);
}
```